# Организация набора констант, используемых в классе

Tags: c++, классы, константа

Я рассматриваю варианты организации набора констант в классе. Константы строковые или других сложных типов (не интегральные). Образуют своеобразную иерархическую структуру, если можно так выразиться. На данный момент есть такой вариант:

```
class X
{
    struct key
    {
        using key_t = std::string;

        struct node
        {
            static const key_t uuid;
            static const key_t word;
        };
    };

    struct path
    {
        using path_t = boost::filesystem::path;

        static const path_t nodes;
    };

    void f()
    {
        // use key::node::word
    }
};

const X::key::key_t X::key::node::uuid = "uuid";
const X::key::key_t X::key::node::word = "word";

const X::path::path_t X::path::nodes = "nodes.json";
```

Все указанные константы используются в функциях-членах класса X. Мне не очень нравится дублирование кода (написание определений для констант) и вызывает сомнения система вложенных структур. Поэтому я решил рассмотреть следующий вариант на namespace-ах:

```
namespace x
{
    namespace key
    {
        using key_t = std::string;

        namespace node
        {
            const key_t uuid = "uuid";
            const key_t word = "word";
        };
    }

    // ...
}

class X
{
    void f()
    {
        // use x::key::node::word
    }
};
```

В такой схеме дублирования нет, также мы избавились от лишних типов-структур, заменив их на пространства имен, но мне не очень нравится наличие внешнего пространства имен x + тот факт, что мы вынесли все эти константы наружу из класса, т.к. константы используются только в классе, фактически являются деталями реализации этого класса.

Порекомендуйте, пожалуйста, какой подход мне избрать при организации подобных наборов констант. Примечание: общее кол-во констант может достигать нескольких десятков.

Comment: Если все константы являются деталями реализации, то их можно поместить в .cpp файл и тем самым скрыть от пользователя класса

Comment: В первом варианте вы можете избавиться от дублирования через inline-определения прямо в классе `static inline const key_t uuid = "uuid";`.